# Minification leads to redeclaration error in FF and IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, minify

We encountered a problem with the minification provided by the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`, as it seems to have problems with `let`. Somehow the minifier sets the name of the variables `bookingDefaultIndex` and `i` to the same name (`i`). This makes Firefox and IE 11 report a scope problem (Firefox reports `SyntaxError: redeclaration of let i`, IE 11 reports `Let/Const redeclaration`), because the variable was already defined. Without minification, the code works just fine in IE and FF. Chrome reports no problems with the minified code.

In the following code snippets, I marked the relevant lines with a comment that starts with `// [SO-COMMENT]`, so you can search for that to see the problematic lines.

This is the unminified function that causes problems:

```js
_handleDDLValuesByContext: function () {
            if (this.options.isCreate) {
                if (this.options.isChildCreation) {
                    //If we are creating a child ->
                    this.$ddlBookingType.val(this.options.data.BookingTypeID);
                    this.$ddlAllocationUnit.val(this.options.data.AllocationUnitID);
                    this.$ddlEffortAllocationUnit.val(this.options.data.AllocationUnitID);

                    if (this.options.data.ServiceCategoryID == null) {
                        this.$ddlServiceCategory.val('-1').trigger('change');
                        if (this.options.data.PricePerUnit != null) {
                            this.$structureRate.val(GetFormat(this.options.data.PricePerUnit));
                        }
                    } else {
                        this.$ddlServiceCategory.val(this.options.data.ServiceCategoryID).trigger('change');
                    }

                    //If we are creating a child, prefill his accounting type with the parent accounting type
                    if (this.options.data.AccountingTypeID == null) {
                        this.$ddlAccountingType.val('-1').trigger('change');
                    } else {
                        this.$ddlAccountingType.val(this.options.data.AccountingTypeID).trigger('change');
                    }
                } else {
                    //If it's parent creation ->
                    let bookingTypes = this.options.structureSpecificData.BookingTypes;
                    let bookingDefaultID = null;
                    // [SO-COMMENT] the following variable is minified to 'i'
                    let bookingDefaultIndex = null;
                    for (let i = 0, len = bookingTypes.length; i < len; i++) {
                        if (bookingTypes[i].IsDefault) {
                            bookingDefaultID = bookingTypes[i].ID;
                            bookingDefaultIndex = i;
                        }
                    }

                    let allocationTypes = this.options.structureSpecificData.AllocationUnitTypes;

                    if (bookingDefaultID == null) {
                        //In case there's no default booking type id, we set the booking types, allocations and effort allocations to their first available value
                        this.$ddlBookingType.val(bookingTypes[0].ID);
                        this.$ddlAllocationUnit.val(allocationTypes[0].ID);
                        this.$ddlEffortAllocationUnit.val(allocationTypes[0].ID);
                    } else {
                        let allocationDefaultID = null;
                        
                        this.$ddlBookingType.val(bookingDefaultID).trigger('change');

                        allocationTypes = [];
                        let bookings = this.options.structureSpecificData.BookingTypes;
                        let allocations = this.options.structureSpecificData.AllocationUnitTypes;
                        
                        // [SO-COMMENT] this is the 'original' i
                        for (let i = 0, len = allocations.length; i < len; i++) {
                            if (allocations[i].BaseUnitID == bookings[bookingDefaultIndex].BaseUnitID) {
                                allocationTypes.push(allocations[i]);
                            }
                        }

                        for (let i = 0, len = allocationTypes.length; i < len; i++) {
                            if (allocationTypes[i].IsDefault) {
                                allocationDefaultID = allocationTypes[i].ID;
                            }
                        }

                        if (allocationDefaultID == null) {
                            this.$ddlAllocationUnit.val(allocationTypes[0].ID);
                            this.$ddlEffortAllocationUnit.val(allocationTypes[0].ID);
                        } else {
                            this.$ddlAllocationUnit.val(allocationDefaultID);
                            this.$ddlEffortAllocationUnit.val(allocationDefaultID);
                        }
                    }
                    this.$ddlServiceCategory.val('-1');
                }
            } else {
                //If we are edditing ->
                this.$ddlBookingType.val(this.options.data.BookingTypeID);
                this.$ddlAllocationUnit.val(this.options.data.AllocationUnitID);
                this.$ddlEffortAllocationUnit.val(this.options.data.AllocationUnitID);
                if (this.options.data.IsParentElement) {
                    this.$ddlServiceCategory.val('-1').trigger('change');

                    //We have to check against a NaN type since the effort and the total cost can be of that type 
                    //in case we have a structure hierarchy with an accounting type of fixed price and therefore no effort and cost
                    if (isNaN(this.options.structureTotalCost)) {
                        this.$structureTotalCost.val('');
                    } else {
                        this.$structureTotalCost.val(GetFormat(this.options.structureTotalCost));
                    }

                    if (isNaN(this.options.structureEffort)) {
                        this.$structureEffortUnits.val('');
                    } else {
                        this.$structureEffortUnits.val(GetFormat(this.options.structureEffort));
                    }
                } else {
                    if (this.options.data.ServiceCategoryID == null) {
                        this.$ddlServiceCategory.val('-1').trigger('change');
                        if (this.options.data.PricePerUnit != null) {
                            this.$structureRate.val(GetFormat(this.options.data.PricePerUnit));
                            this._checkTotalCostCalculation();
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (this.options.data.PricePerUnit !== null) {
                            this.$structureRate.val(GetFormat(this.options.data.PricePerUnit));
                            this.$ddlServiceCategory.val(this.options.data.ServiceCategoryID);
                            this._checkTotalCostCalculation();
                        } else {
                            this.$ddlServiceCategory.val(this.options.data.ServiceCategoryID).trigger('change');
                        }
                    }
                }

                //Since we are editing we should prefill the accounting type with the accounting id and the fixed price too if it exists
                //And not trigger anything
                if (this.options.data.AccountingTypeID == null) {
                    this.$ddlAccountingType.val('-1').trigger('change');
                } else {
                    this.$ddlAccountingType.val(this.options.data.AccountingTypeID).trigger('change');
                }
                if (isNaN(this.options.totalFixedPrice)) {
                    this.$fixedPrice.val('');
                } else {
                    this.$fixedPrice.val(GetFormat(this.options.totalFixedPrice));
                }
                
            }
        }
```

And this is the minified version:

```js
_handleDDLValuesByContext: function() {
                if (this.options.isCreate)
                    if (this.options.isChildCreation) this.$ddlBookingType.val(this.options.data.BookingTypeID), this.$ddlAllocationUnit.val(this.options.data.AllocationUnitID), this.$ddlEffortAllocationUnit.val(this.options.data.AllocationUnitID), this.options.data.ServiceCategoryID == null ? (this.$ddlServiceCategory.val("-1").trigger("change"), this.options.data.PricePerUnit != null && this.$structureRate.val(GetFormat(this.options.data.PricePerUnit))) : this.$ddlServiceCategory.val(this.options.data.ServiceCategoryID).trigger("change"), this.options.data.AccountingTypeID == null ? this.$ddlAccountingType.val("-1").trigger("change") : this.$ddlAccountingType.val(this.options.data.AccountingTypeID).trigger("change");
                    else {
                        let t = this.options.structureSpecificData.BookingTypes,
                            i = null, // [SO-COMMENT] this shouldn't be named i
                            r = null;
                        for (let n = 0, u = t.length; n < u; n++) t[n].IsDefault && (i = t[n].ID, r = n);
                        let n = this.options.structureSpecificData.AllocationUnitTypes;
                        if (i == null) this.$ddlBookingType.val(t[0].ID), this.$ddlAllocationUnit.val(n[0].ID), this.$ddlEffortAllocationUnit.val(n[0].ID);
                        else {
                            let t = null;
                            this.$ddlBookingType.val(i).trigger("change");
                            n = [];
                            let f = this.options.structureSpecificData.BookingTypes,
                                u = this.options.structureSpecificData.AllocationUnitTypes;
                            for (let t = 0, i = u.length; t < i; t++) u[t].BaseUnitID == f[r].BaseUnitID && n.push(u[t]);
                            // [SO-COMMENT] here there is a second i that causes the problem
                            for (let i = 0, r = n.length; i < r; i++) n[i].IsDefault && (t = n[i].ID);
                            t == null ? (this.$ddlAllocationUnit.val(n[0].ID), this.$ddlEffortAllocationUnit.val(n[0].ID)) : (this.$ddlAllocationUnit.val(t), this.$ddlEffortAllocationUnit.val(t))
                        }
                        this.$ddlServiceCategory.val("-1")
                    } else this.$ddlBookingType.val(this.options.data.BookingTypeID), this.$ddlAllocationUnit.val(this.options.data.AllocationUnitID), this.$ddlEffortAllocationUnit.val(this.options.data.AllocationUnitID), this.options.data.IsParentElement ? (this.$ddlServiceCategory.val("-1").trigger("change"), isNaN(this.options.structureTotalCost) ? this.$structureTotalCost.val("") : this.$structureTotalCost.val(GetFormat(this.options.structureTotalCost)), isNaN(this.options.structureEffort) ? this.$structureEffortUnits.val("") : this.$structureEffortUnits.val(GetFormat(this.options.structureEffort))) : this.options.data.ServiceCategoryID == null ? (this.$ddlServiceCategory.val("-1").trigger("change"), this.options.data.PricePerUnit != null && (this.$structureRate.val(GetFormat(this.options.data.PricePerUnit)), this._checkTotalCostCalculation())) : this.options.data.PricePerUnit !== null ? (this.$structureRate.val(GetFormat(this.options.data.PricePerUnit)), this.$ddlServiceCategory.val(this.options.data.ServiceCategoryID), this._checkTotalCostCalculation()) : this.$ddlServiceCategory.val(this.options.data.ServiceCategoryID).trigger("change"), this.options.data.AccountingTypeID == null ? this.$ddlAccountingType.val("-1").trigger("change") : this.$ddlAccountingType.val(this.options.data.AccountingTypeID).trigger("change"), isNaN(this.options.totalFixedPrice) ? this.$fixedPrice.val("") : this.$fixedPrice.val(GetFormat(this.options.totalFixedPrice))
            }
```

My google searches for IIS minification scope problems didn't show any useful results. What could we try to investigate and fix this problem, other than not to use `let`?

Comment: I dont think IIS itself is doing the minification. Ive seen minification done via modules installed into IIS, or done via the application itself (or as part of the deployment process/CI system).  Have you got any custom modules installed into IIS, or libraries in your app itself that might be the root cause? Config inside `<appsettings />` implies its part of your app?

Comment: You are right, not the IIS does this, but the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`. I corrected that in my question. There seems to be nothing special about how we configure the bundling, and it works for the rest of the application, except for the given example.